# How to flag a function parameter as a parameter name?

Tags: c#

If you construct an ArgumentException, one of the parameters is the paramName of the parameter that you're checking.  If you pass the parameter name as a string like this:

```
throw new ArgumentException("That's a stupid name", "userName");
```

you'll get a "hint" that says "use 'nameof' expression to reference parameter 'userName' name." Even better, if the name you pass it doesn't match a parameter to the calling function, you'll get a warning that says "cannot resolve symbol 'wrongName'".

My question is: How does it know?  I have some Assert like functions where I pass the parameter name, and I want them to get the same behavior, but I can't find the way to do it.

I seem to recall seeing somewhere a while back that this was done by tagging the parameter with some attribute, but I can't find it now.  I found CallerArgumentExpressionAttribute, but that seems to be something different and was added in C# 10.

I'm using C# 9, by the way.

Comment: The compiler sees all the code. It analyzes the parameters by comparing their names.

Comment: Presumably there is an analyzer for it. `CallerArgumentExpression` is something else, that could be used to generate the `paramName` by just doing `new YourException(userName);`

Comment: This warning is being generated by an analyzer. Most of them are here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers
Maybe you can find the implementation by searching the warning Rule ID (E.g. CA1000)

Comment: I found the analyzer for this.  It specifically looks for an argument named "paramName".  Changing mine to that, I got it to give me a hint, but ArgumentException makes it more of a warning. I wonder if Resharper is adding its own analyzer.

Comment: @dwilliss I tested in Rider and see what you are saying. Both the call to argumentException and my own custom method triggered CA1507 but the ArgumentException issue is more prominent within the IDE.